# Galois connection for homeomorphisms

Tags: galois-theory, homeomorphism

let $M = \mathbb{R^2}$ and $X = \{0\}$ and $G = Aut_X(M)$ the group of homeorphisms fixing $X$ (pointwise). Then we have, in analogy to classical Galois theory for field extensions, a Galois connection between the topological subspaces $ \{0\} \subseteq Y \subseteq M$ and the subgroups $U \subseteq G$ via $Y' := Stab(Y) \subseteq G$ and $U' := Fix(U) \subseteq M$.

Of course, in this case, there is no 1-1 correspondence, as not all $Y$ and $U$ are Galois-closed, i.e. $Y''=Y$, $U''=U$ is only true for certain $Y$ and $U$. The Galois-closed $Y$ are obviously exactly the topologically closed $Y$, and the Galois-closed $U$ are exactly the pointwise stabilizer groups $U=Y'= Stab(Y) $ for some $Y$.

Obviously, each Galois-closed $U=U''$ is the Galois-closure to an infinite number of subgroups $V \subseteq U$, which also satisfy $V''=U$, e.g. all the subgroups of $C^k$-diffeomorphisms.

I want to describe this set $S$ of subgroups $V \subseteq U$ satisfying $V''=U$.

In particular, I would like to know what the intersection $U^-$ of all sets in $S$ is?

Is $U^- = \{e\}$?

Comment: Why can't we get $U^-=\{e\}$ by observing that $S$ contains the group of piecewise linear homeomorphisms with piecewise linear inverses that fix our closed set along with the group of $C^\infty$-diffeoomorphisms fixing the closed set?

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like the solution.